# Link to Entities Aggregate method replacement

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

It looks like the Linq to Entities doesn't support `Aggregate` method. I need to rewrite this `.Select(a => a.Permissions).Aggregate((a, b) => a | b)` part of bigger expression to something that Linq to Entities understands. Is it possible?

Maybe I should give you a better explanation of what am I doing. I need to get a collection of Organizers from database based on user permissions to these Organizers. Permissions are stored as bit flags and are a combination of the following:

1. DefaultOrganizerPermissions - Every Organizer has some default Permissions
2. OwnerPermissions - If User is the owner of the Organizer, he has some additional permission
3. UserPermisions - Users can be manually assigned to have some Permissions to Organizer
4. RolePermissions - Users can be members of roles and these roles can be assigned to have an additional permissions to Organizers.

So I have a method with the following signature

`public IQueryable<Organizer> GetOrganizers(Person person, OrganizerPermissions requiredPermissions)`

and inside it there is a code like this

```
organizers = organizers.Where(o => ((
        // Default permissions
        DefaultOrganizerPermissions |
        // Owner permissions
        (o.OwnerId == person.Id ? OwnerOrganizerPermissions : 0) |
        // Personal permissions
        (o.AccessIdentifier.Accesses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Accessor is PersonalAccessor && (a.Accessor as PersonalAccessor).PersonId == person.Id) != null ?
        (OrganizerPermissions)o.AccessIdentifier.Accesses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Accessor is PersonalAccessor && (a.Accessor as PersonalAccessor).PersonId == person.Id).Permissions : 0) |
        // Role permissions
        (o.AccessIdentifier.Accesses.Any(a => a.Accessor is RoleAccessor && (a.Accessor as RoleAccessor).Role.RoleMembers.Any(rm=>rm.PersonId == person.Id)) ?
        (OrganizerPermissions)o.AccessIdentifier.Accesses.Where(a=> a.Accessor is RoleAccessor && (a.Accessor as RoleAccessor).Role.RoleMembers.Any(rm => rm.PersonId == person.Id)).Select(a=>a.Permissions).Aggregate((a, b) => a | b) : 0)
        ) & requiredPermissions) == requiredPermissions);
```

Simplified it is something like this:

```
organizers = organizers.Where(o => ((
        DefaultOrganizerPermissions |
        OwnerOrganizerPermissions |
        UserPermisions  |
        RolePermissions
        ) & requiredPermissions) == requiredPermissions);
```

The problem is that user can be member of multiple Roles, so RolePermissions are actually multiple permissions and I need to flatten it down with bitwise OR. But how, if Aggregate is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of data isn't prohibitively large, you could consider calling `.ToList()` before the `Select(...)` statement to read the data into memory and then perform the Aggregate as Linq to Objects

Comment: Did you try this? ....ToList().Select(a => a.Permissions).Aggregate((a, b) => a | b)  ToList() materializes the query (so is bad) but it should work... You have also other ways, i.e. Sum or select just one that is true (FirstOrDefault) but you should be more explicit.

Comment: @bubi Yes, I did. I am acually using ToList() in another method in the same class and it works. But it doesn't work in this one. I think it is strange, I would expect it to either work, or to raise some (different) error, but there is no change. I just need somehow merge multiple bit flags (they are represented as integers), like for instance 1010 | 0011 = 1011. I don't know if it is possible with Sum.

Comment: @PetrHruzek: what do you mean by there is no change? if you separately execute the part with aggregate, do you just get 0?

Comment: @jjj: No change means it always throws an exception

`Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Aggregate[Int32] System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32], System.Func`3[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`.

I can successfully execute the aggregate part after the ToList(), if it is the last statement of the expression tree. But I need to execute it as a part of larger query, i.e. in the middle of expression tree, that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If Permissions is nullable you probably need to insert
a.Permissions.GetValueOrDefault()
so the query should be
.Select(a => a.Permissions.GetValueOrDefault()).Aggregate((a, b) => a | b)

Also, if the EF provider does not support Aggregate translation to SQL (this part is provider specific so it could work with one DBMS but not with a different DBMS) you need to materialize the query with ToList() (like suggested by @sjager).

**EDIT**
The problem is that EF provider does not support Aggregate translation to SQL.

I'm not a SQL Server expert anyway you should find an **aggregate** function (like SUM or AVG) that makes what you need (bitwise OR). In MySQL is BIT_OR().

If it does not exist then GAME OVER

If it exists you can view the source code of EF provider for SQL Server and view wich LINQ function is translated into that or ask another question-

Comment: Permissions in not nullable, it has always a value. I can successfully execute the aggregate part after the ToList(), if it is the last statement of the expression tree. But I need to execute it as a part of larger query, i.e. in the middle of expression tree, that is the problem.

Comment: What is the exception if you don't insert ToList? Or is SQL Server the problem? In this case you can trace the query and try to run it on SQL Server and see what happens.

Comment: It is `An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Aggregate[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable``1[System.Int32], System.Func``3[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.` Link to Entities simply doesn't know how to translate Aggregate method to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, I've run in to the exact same situation yesterday.
So, as @bubi stated, without a SQL server proper aggregate function it's **not possible**.

The way I've worked around it is - create a bunch of OR expressions groups for each role, each of them having a comparison with a role of user. After that, connect all "OR expression groups" with AND predicate.

E.g. if user has 0011 enum value, then you'll need to create OR predicates for both 0001 and 0010 flags. 0001 flag "OR group" would look like

```
x=> x.Equals(0001) || x.Equals(0011) || x.Equals(0101)| || ..)
```

But it's definitely not recommended.